# How to test spring ScheduledExecutorTask

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a test job which trows an exception. I would like to test that the exception is catched and after the correspondent period, the job is executed again.

Following the [spring example](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-maintenance/tags/release-2-0/tiger/test/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorFactoryBeanTests.java), I couldn´t figure it out. The imports are deprecated. How could I prove that fact using mockito?

The job:

```
public class TestScheduler implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void runScheduled(){
        LOGGER.info("Doing my tasks...");
        throw new RuntimeException("Testing purpose");
    }
}
```

Config:

```
<bean id="testScheduler" class="com.scheduler.TestScheduler"/>
    <bean id="testSchedulerTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask">
        <property name="delay" value="10"/>
        <property name="period" value="60"/>
        <property name="runnable" ref="testScheduler"/>
    </bean>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple test, if someone has a better idea, I would be very glad to improve my code.

```
public class TestSchedulerIT extends SpringIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    TestScheduler testScheduler;

    @Mock
    TestScheduler.TestProperty testString;


    @Test
    public void testFixedRepeatedExecutionIsSetupAndFiresCorrectly() throws Exception {
        int period = 500;

        //Set test string
        when(testString.getProperty()).thenReturn("Testing");
        testScheduler.setTest(testString);

        ScheduledExecutorTask task = new ScheduledExecutorTask(testScheduler);
        task.setPeriod(period);
        task.setDelay(0);

        ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean factory = new ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean();
        factory.setScheduledExecutorTasks(new ScheduledExecutorTask[]{task});
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        pauseToLetTaskStart(period + 1000);
        verify(testString, atLeast(2)).getProperty(); //Verify that the job has been run at least 2 times regardless the exception
        factory.destroy();
    }
```

In the TestScheduler I added this property:

```
public class TestProperty{
        private String property;

        TestProperty(String property){
            this.property = property;
        }

        public String getProperty() {
            return property;
        }
    }
```